# Algoritmo envolvendo estatística

Tags: matlab, redes-neurais

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de TCC que utilizou redes neurais no MATLAB como aproximador universal de funções, tendo obtido resultados muito bons: mais de 70% das amostras apresentam erro relativo de menos de 10% em relação ao valor real, e 60% do total apresenta erro de menos de 5% em relação ao valor real.

No entanto, eu sei quais valores os resultados deveriam assumir, são alguns valores discretos, todos conhecidos. Eu gostaria de aprimorar meu trabalho, usando algum método para aproximar os valores obtidos pela rede para os valores reais, isso é possível? Existe algum algoritmo, ou alguma análise estatística que eu possa usar?

Por exemplo: se eu criar um vetor com todos os valores possíveis (são 171 valores possíveis), e comparar os valores encontrados pela rede com os valores possíveis, e aproximar para o mais próximo, eu consigo resolver esse problema para os que apresentam erro relativo baixo, o que dá cerca de 70% do total. Mas, supondo que eu não saiba o erro relativo, existe algum método que eu possa aumentar a eficiência do meu trabalho?

Answer (score -3):

você pode usar a técnica de boostraping na sua base de dados

a técnica consiste em aumentar o volume de dados do seu dataset, com base nos dados existentes, ele cria exemplos aleatórios seguindo algum tipo de distribuição.

como você já sabe quais resultados alguns conjuntos de dados devem gerar, crie um dataset separado apenas com as combinações que você saiba os resultados, rode algum algoritmo para dar um boostrap nessa segunda base, Depois basta unir os dois datasets em um dataset final e treinar o seu modelo com esse dataset final

como vão ter mais exemplos das combinações corretas para um determinado resultado, o modelo vai aprender melhor